# Make JSON Data from HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

I'm new to this, so I'm asking for help. It seems to me that it should be simple enough. I have a piece of HTML code like this:

```
    <div class="shopping-cart-list">
    <div>
        <div class="toReceipt" style="display: none;">
            <div class="toReceiptName">Position 1</div>
            <div class="toReceiptPrice">200</div>
            <div class="toReceiptQuantity">2</div>
            <div class="toReceiptAmount">400</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="toReceipt" style="display: none;">
            <div class="toReceiptName">Position 2</div>
            <div class="toReceiptPrice">100</div>
            <div class="toReceiptQuantity">1</div>
            <div class="toReceiptAmount">100</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="toReceipt" style="display: none;">
            <div class="toReceiptName">Position 3</div>
            <div class="toReceiptPrice">20</div>
            <div class="toReceiptQuantity">2</div>
            <div class="toReceiptAmount">40</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need to make JSON Data as below. If I understand correctly, then you need to parse HTML code and conver it to JSON. Accordingly, positions are repeated in JSON like in HTML and below you I to calculate the total amount. How can I do this?

```
var receipt = {
    "Items": [{
            "label": "Position 1",
            "price": 200.00,
            "quantity": 2.00,
            "amount": 400.00,
        },
        {
            "label": "Position 2",
            "price": 100.00,
            "quantity": 1.00,
            "amount": 100.00,
        },
        {
            "label": "Position 3",
            "price": 20.00,
            "quantity": 2.00,
            "amount": 40.00,
        },
    ],
    "amounts": {
        "electronic": 1300.00, // Calculate amount of all positions
    }
}
```

Comment: 400 + 100 + 40 = 1300 ? What's the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```js
function go() {
  let result = {
    "Item": [],
    "amounts": {}
  };
  let totalAmount = 0;
  $("div.shopping-cart-list div.toReceipt").each((index, item) => {
    result.Item.push({
      "label": $(item).find("div.toReceiptName").text(),
      "price": Number($(item).find("div.toReceiptPrice").text()),
      "quantity": Number($(item).find("div.toReceiptQuantity").text()),
      "amount": Number($(item).find("div.toReceiptAmount").text())
    })
    totalAmount += Number($(item).find("div.toReceiptAmount").text());
  });
  result.amounts = {
    "electronic": totalAmount
  };
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="shopping-cart-list">
  <div>
    <div class="toReceipt" style="display: none;">
      <div class="toReceiptName">Position 1</div>
      <div class="toReceiptPrice">200</div>
      <div class="toReceiptQuantity">2</div>
      <div class="toReceiptAmount">400</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="toReceipt" style="display: none;">
      <div class="toReceiptName">Position 2</div>
      <div class="toReceiptPrice">100</div>
      <div class="toReceiptQuantity">1</div>
      <div class="toReceiptAmount">100</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="toReceipt" style="display: none;">
      <div class="toReceiptName">Position 3</div>
      <div class="toReceiptPrice">20</div>
      <div class="toReceiptQuantity">2</div>
      <div class="toReceiptAmount">40</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="go()">
Go
</button>
```